# Will a Tiefling be born to a Tiefling/Human couple?

Tags: dnd-5e, tiefling

Tieflings in 5th edition are a playable race but are tieflings specifically born to two tiefling parents?  Or will a tiefling always beget a tiefling child if he/she mates with another (standard being human) race?

Or is it a case of tiefling children being born at random out of certain bloodlines?

Comment: I think this would depend heavily on the setting. Which did you have in mind? The "default" for 5e is Forgotten Realms.

Comment: related https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/97766/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**It's always a tiefling offspring.**

The PHB, in the section on tieflings says (emphasis mine),

> Their appearance and their nature are not their fault but the result of an ancient sin, for which they ***and their children and their children's children*** will always be held accountable.

Based on that, I would say a tiefling/human pairing would result in a tiefling. The offspring may have less fiendish features than your average tiefling, though that would be a character choice one would make/discuss with the DM.

**Taking it a step further...**

If we make the assumption that since tieflings can interbreed with humans, they can interbreed with the other races that humans tend to interbreed with - e.g. elves and orcs - they would still be in the bloodline of the original pact. So a hypothetical elf/tiefling pairing would yield tiefling offspring. Though, again, the player and the DM could have some fun with that in terms of game mechanics. Maybe that elf/tiefling (elfling?) has the Fey Ancestry trait in place of one of the tiefling racial traits.